# Помогите разобрать код

Tags: javascript

К ак он работает последовательно, что откуда и куда, некоторые моменты непонятны...

```
function showPrimes(n) {
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if(!isPrime(i)) continue;
     alert(i);
    }
   
}

showPrimes(10)
function isPrime(n) {
  for(let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if(n % i == 0) return false;
   }
    return true;
  }
```

Как все последовательно по пунктам, откуда значение берется, как переходит и куда, и вот здесь тоже конкретнее if(!isPrime(i)) , почему именно параметр берется i, как это переходит от функции к функции последовательно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Общий смысл в том, что у тебя есть функция isPrime в которую ты передаешь как аргумент число из текущей итерации цикла функции showPrimes()

```js
/*
/ Функция показа простых чисел в промежутке до N
*/
function showPrimes(n) {
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) { //Перебираем числа от 2 до N
    if(!isPrime(i)) continue; //Передаем число внутри цикла как параметр для ф-ии , проверяющей число на простоту
     alert(i); 
    }
   
}

showPrimes(10)

/*
* Ф-я проверяющая число на простоту
* Простое число — число, имеющее ровно два различных натуральных делителя — единицу и самого себя.
*/
function isPrime(n) {
 //Перебираем все числа в промежутке от 2 до текущего, переданного в ф-ю как агрумент
  for(let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if(n % i == 0) return false; //Если число делиться без остатка на число отличное от 1 и самого числа  - возвращем false - число не простое
   }
   //Иначе - TRUE - число простое
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное, ты очень быстро помог мне разобраться с этим кодом, щас еще устоканю в голове последовательность. Я только начинаю учить функции, и хочу сразу разобраться что к чему, вроде все понятно пока, но каша есть, нужно все собрать в кучу. Вот как все я описал, в принципе оно так и происходит получается ?

Comment: В общем да. В такой ситуации , когда прям совсем начинающий, могу посоветовать способ, который нам в институте давали: берешь листик бумаги и записываешь код на нем и какие значения переменной в каждой итерации цикла - быстро поймешь, что откуда и куда передается.

Comment: А если получается условие цикла выполнилось, то есть                                                                    
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) { 
    if(!isPrime(i)) continue;  и                                                                                                            
   for(let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if(n % i == 0) return false;    То они увеличиваются на 1, то есть i будет в обоих случаях уже 3, и будет сравнение повышенного числа в i со следующим которое увеличилось в n ? Вообщем 4 % 2 == 0, не выполнилось, дальше сравниваем 5 % 3 == 0 ? Потом сбрасываем до 2